# VBA Auto Row Insert by Starting Letter

Tags: excel, vba, automation, spreadsheet

Is there a way I can use VBA to search any of the rows in column A for the letter Q and if letter Q is the first letter in that row than the Macro would automatically hit insert on that row separating it from the previous one.

I essentially want to insert a row above every time the letter Q is the first letter of a row...

Comment: A loop, as well as the function `Left`, should work. Can you share the `If...Then` you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of things can be done while combining *super basic tutorials*.

Find a tutorial how to loop through range, then how to get first letter in a cell and then how to insert row, then understand that while inserting/deleting  it is better to loop from top to bottom:

```
Sub InsertRowBeforeQ()
    For i = 20 To 1 Step -1
        If Left$(Range("A" & i), 1) = "Q" Then Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Insert
    Next i
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: So I have added a whole plethora of other formatting things but the one I am most confused by following this would be not just coloring any row that starts with Q but also the two rows after the one that starts with Q

Comment: I don't think I follow you. Post is about inserting row, not coloring anything :)

Comment: Yes I am looking for another piece but with the same search reference.